# How do I disable scripts in my iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe that loads a page that I would like to disable the javascripts loading in the iframe loaded page.  The loaded page has menu bars, dropdowns, etc. that make the home page that I am loading this iframe from load slow.  Is there a way to disable javascript from my iframe page?

I need the javascripts to remain in the page because the visitor can visit the page.

Here is my code for loading the iframe:

```
<div style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; width: 800; height:400; left:-170px; top:0px;">
<iframe src="/News/Pages/Default.aspx" style="overflow:hidden; width:100%; height:650;"
      frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe></div>
```

If this is not possible, than is there a way to stop/disable the iframe page from loading the .js files.  The iframe page loads .js files, no javascript is inline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the last code example on this page, http://www.iframehtml.com/iframe-scripts.html

Shows a method of stripping JavaScript from the iframe's source file using PHP

Comment: "There are a couple of ways to do this, but not with JavaScript. PHP code is the most reliable as you can simply strip the Javascript out of the site..."

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, I dont think you can disable loading of javascripts in the Iframe. Best way is, avoid script tags in the iframe page.