# Disabling javascript in a child window, from the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Bit of an weird request, but I'd like to be able to have a parent window:

- Create a new child window on the same domain (using `window.open`)
- **Prevent any javascript running in the child window**

Currently, I can do this *within* in the child window by including the following at the very top of the page:

```
<script>
  Function.prototype.call = function() {};
  Function.prototype.apply = function() {};
</script>
```

This pretty much stops any javascript in the child page from running. But is there any way for me to do this **from the parent window**? Can I somehow inject this code into the child page before any scripts have a chance to run?

Or is there any other way to do this?

Any help appreciated

Comment: If you're directing the child window to an URL, the Same Origin Policy would prevent you from manipulating that page.

Comment: @Diodeus The child page will be on the same domain, so I can manipulate it as much as I like.

Comment: Redefining `Function`'s prototype [doesn't seem to actually work](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/6y7aq/)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bit of server side to remove all `<script>` tags and inline event handlers like `onclick`.

**EDIT**

using client side you can try to grab whole page using ajax remove the scripts there and write the content to newly created window. I don't think you will be able to use

```
$.get('page.html', function(html) {
    var html = $(html).find('script').remove().html();
});
```

because scripts may be executed when added to DOM, so maybe you will need to use a parser or just regex.

Comment: Good suggestion, but for various reasons this needs to be purely client side.

Comment: Thanks jcubic, I think this is going to be the best approach. Little bit hacky, but should achieve what I'm hoping to do.

Answer (score 2):

`window.open()` returns a reference to the newly created window.  If the window is on the same origin, you're free to access it.

```
var popup = window.open('/some/page.html');
popup.contentWindow // = the popup's `window` object
```

**However,** the code you've come up with [doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/6y7aq/).  You've likely seen that it breaks jQuery, which makes liberal use of `call` and `apply`, but it does nothing to stop normal function invocation.

Comment: Yeah, you're absolutely correct, I was seeing it break jQuery and assuming the same effect for other js. Thanks for pointing this out to me.

Answer (score 0):

If the child window is in an `iframe`? There has been a question like that, and the answer was - you can not do this easily with php serverside.

[How do I disable scripts in my iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839891/how-do-i-disable-scripts-in-my-iframe)

Comment: Nope, not an iframe, a child window created with `window.open(...)`. I have full control over the window, I just need to know how to run the above javascript-blocking code *before* the child page has a chance to load any other js.